# EF Core Database.EnsureCreated get creating table SQL and without sending request to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I use EF Core - `Database.EnsureCreated` to create table by C# class, but now I'd like to get only creating table and columns SQL and without sending request to database.

e.g

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Dto> Dtos{ get; set; }
}

public class Dto
{
  [Key]
  [StringLength(10)]
    public string ID{ get; set; }
  [StringLength(100)]
  [Required]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
  [Required]
  public int Age{ get; set; }
}

db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
```

Expected result :

```cs
create table Dto
{
  ID nvarchar(10) primary key not null,
  Name nvarchar(100) not null,
  Age int not null
}
```

What I tried?

I did open SSMS profile and get SQL from EF Core, but it needs to send request to database.

Comment: You need to call `IRelationalDatabaseCreator.GenerateCreateScript()` via the extension method `db.Database.GenerateCreateScript()`. (https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/f62cf1b1fa45d6026e8f98113d6d6712d81094c3/src/EFCore.Relational/Extensions/RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.cs#L819)

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Thanks, you answer resolve the problem perfectly! Could u answer below? I'll mark it answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My usual approach to these types of questions is to poke around in the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore). I found the implementation of [`.EnsureCreated()`](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/cc53b3e80755e5d882bb21ef10e0e0e33194d9bd/src/EFCore.Relational/Storage/RelationalDatabaseCreator.cs#L131), then noticed that there is a public method to `.GenerateCreateScript()` on the same type. Searching the entire code base for calls to that method reveals an extension method on [`DatabaseFacade`](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/f62cf1b1fa45d6026e8f98113d6d6712d81094c3/src/EFCore.Relational/Extensions/RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.cs#L819). So all you need to do is;

```cs
var sqlSource = db.Database.GenerateCreateScript();
```

However using google to search for that method doesn't reveal any results in the official documentation. The "proper" way to create a production database is to create migrations, then create an sql script to apply them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dotnet EF CLI to run the migrations script:

```
dotnet ef migrations script -i -o "C:\MYFOLDER\dbscript.sql"
```

REF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet